# Populate dataframe columns based on formula and count using columns from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe of writers like this:

| writer_id | titles |
| --- | --- |
| n1 | t1,t2 |
| n2 | t3,t4 |

And I have another dataframe for the titles with genre, ratings and votes like this:

| title_id | genres | votes | rating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| t1 | Drama,Action | 100 | 7.0 |
| t2 | Action,Thriller | 1000 | 8.0 |
| t3 | Crime ,Romance | 200 | 6.0 |
| t4 | Drama,Romance | 300 | 5.0 |

Now in the new data frame, I want to have a row for each writer with columns for each genre with the count value and another column (let's call it popularity) that will apply a formula using votes and rating. So it would look like this:

| writer_id | drama | action | thriller | romance | crime | popularity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| n1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2.2 |
| n2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 4.2 |

How should I go about doing this? I have the columns with genres already created.

Comment: What is formula?

Comment: for sake of simplicity , let's say it is : (w * (rating)) + (6.0 * (1-w)) where w = (votes / max(votes)). Hope it is clear. Thanks!

Comment: hmmm, how is count `2.2` ? what is `w` for `writer_id=n1`?

Comment: I am using dummy values for the popularity. It is not the actual value. But assume 0.8 for w.

Comment: I am confused, by formula. `(w * (rating)) + (6.0 * (1-w)) where w = (votes / max(votes))` - how values for `n1` is necessary use from your sample data? e.g `0.8` is count `w = (votes / max(votes))` is `w = (??? / 8.0)`

Comment: it means `???` is `6.4` - so `6.4 / 8.0 = 0.8` ?

Comment: Ah sorry about that. Let me use a better example formula : (votes1*rating1 + ..+ votesN*ratingsN) / (votes1+..+votesN). So for n1, ( (100*7.0) + (1000 * 8.0) ) / (1000 + 100). Hope that helps.

Comment: It is not count from `df` after `merge` ? Added to answer.

Comment: That’s right. Count is only needed for genre columns which you have already answered. It’s not needed for popularity columns.

Comment: output is correct in solution bellow?

Comment: Awesome, I am going to test it out soon and mark your answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First part is [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) by comma separated values in both DataFrames and [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html), for counts use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df11 = (df1.assign(title_id= df1['titles'].str.split(','))
           .explode('title_id')
           .drop('titles', 1))
df22 = (df2.assign(genres= df2['genres'].str.split(','))
           .explode('genres'))

df = df11.merge(df22, on='title_id') 

print (df)
  writer_id title_id    genres  votes  rating
0        n1       t1     Drama    100     7.0
1        n1       t1    Action    100     7.0
2        n1       t2    Action   1000     8.0
3        n1       t2  Thriller   1000     8.0
4        n2       t3     Crime    200     6.0
5        n2       t3   Romance    200     6.0
6        n2       t4     Drama    300     5.0
7        n2       t4   Romance    300     5.0

#count weight mean from df after `merge`
df4 = (df.assign(w = lambda x: x['votes'].mul(x['rating']))
         .groupby('writer_id')
         .sum()
         .assign(w = lambda x: x['w'].div(x['votes'])))

df3 = pd.crosstab(df['writer_id'], df['genres']).assign(popularity = df4['w'])
print (df3)
genres     Action  Crime  Drama  Romance  Thriller  popularity
writer_id                                                     
n1              2      0      1        0         1    7.909091
n2              0      1      1        2         0    5.400000
```